# Perl eval Data::Dumper inconsistency

Tags: perl, serialization, deserialization, eval, data-dumper

I have to serialize and deserialize in Perl. I am aware that `Data::Dumper` and `eval` are not the best suited ones for this job but I am not allowed to modify this aspect in the legacy scripts which I am working on.
Below are two ways ( **CODE 1** and **CODE 2** ) to use `eval`.
In **CODE 1**, the hash is available as a string before being deserialized via `eval`.
In **CODE 2**, the hash is serialized using `Dumper` before being deserialized via `eval`.

In both the code samples, one of two attempted ways to deserialize works.  Why does the other way to deserialize not work ?

**CODE 1**

```
my $r2 = "( 
'w' => {
           'k2' => 5,
           'k1' => 'key',
           'k3' => [
                     'a',
                     'b',
                     2,
                     '3'
                   ]
         },
  'q' => 2 
)"; 

my %z; 
eval "\%z = $r2";          ####### Works. 
print "\%z = [".Data::Dumper::Dumper (\%z)."] "; 

my $answer = eval "$r2";   #### Does NOT work. 
print "\n\nEvaled = [".Dumper($answer)."] ";
```

**Output**

```
%z = [$VAR1 = {
          'w' => {
                   'k2' => 5,
                   'k1' => 'key',
                   'k3' => [
                             'a',
                             'b',
                             2,
                             '3'
                           ]
                 },
          'q' => 2
        };
]

Evaled = [$VAR1 = 2;
]
```

But below code works in reverse manner :
**CODE 2**

```
my %a = ( "q" =>2, "w"=>{ "k1"=>"key", "k2"=>5, k3=>["a", "b", 2, "3",], }, );  **# Same hash as above example.** 
$Data::Dumper::Terse=1; 
$Data::Dumper::Purity = 1; 
my $r2 = Dumper(\%a); 

my %z; 
eval '\%z = $r2'; 
print "\n\n\%z = [".Dumper(\%z)."] ";         #### Does NOT work. 

my $answer = eval $r2; 
print "\n\nEvaled = [".Dumper($answer)."] ";  ####### Works.
```

**Output**

```
%z = [$VAR1 = {};
]

Evaled = [$VAR1 = {
          'w' => {
                   'k2' => 5,
                   'k1' => 'key',
                   'k3' => [
                             'a',
                             'b',
                             2,
                             '3'
                           ]
                 },
          'q' => 2
        };
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, please don't put comments that result in syntax errors (`**`).

Notice that the string you provided in the first code block produces different data structure than the Dumper function. In the first block you are creating a hash, but you don't assign it to any variable. In case of the Dumper function, anonymous hash is created and it's reference is passed to the `$VAR` variable.

To make the first code work, you should replace `(` with `{` to create anonymous hash and then assign it to a variable, for example:

```
my $r2 = "$VAR = { 
    'w' => {
           'k2' => 5,
           'k1' => 'key',
           'k3' => [
                     'a',
                     'b',
                     2,
                     '3'
                   ]
         },
  'q' => 2 
}";
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. Currently, i am using pattern match and replace to change the leading and trailing curly braces with round brackets. Could we do it in any other way too ? Also, I have removed the stars. I should have put them behind the #.

Comment: You don't need to change all that data. Merely change how you make the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Data::Dumper to serialize data. Having said that...

This is a problem of scalar and list context. In the second eval, you have:

```
my $answer = ...;
```

Since you are assigning to a scalar, the right side is evaluated in scalar context. That means the `eval` is in scalar context. That value is:

```
(
'w' => {
           'k2' => 5,
           'k1' => 'key',
           'k3' => [
                     'a',
                     'b',
                     2,
                     '3'
                   ]
         },
  'q' => 2
)
```

That looks like a list, but it's really the comma operator in scalar context. That evaluates the left hand side, discards that result, and returns the righthand side. So, `my $x = ( 'left', 'right' )` assigns `right` to `$x`. This is covered in [What is the difference between a list and an array?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#What-is-the-difference-between-a-list-and-an-array%3f) in [perlfaq4](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html).

In your question, you see that `$r` gets the value `2`. That's the rightmost value in the comma chain, so that's the value you get back in scalar context. Change that to another value (perhaps `'duck'`), and that's the value that you'll get back:

```
my $r2 = "(
    'w' => {
               'k2' => 5,
             },
      'q' => 'duck'
    )";

my $answer = eval "$r2";

use Data::Dumper;
print "Evaled =\n" . Dumper($answer);
```

It's not a number, which confuses people because they think it's some sort of count:

```
Evaled =
$VAR1 = 'duck';
```

Change that to assign in list context (that hash assignment is a list assignment) and you get the right answer:

```
my $r2 = "(
    'w' => {
               'k2' => 5,
             },
      'q' => 'duck'
    )";

my @answer = eval "$r2";

use Data::Dumper;
print "Evaled =\n" . Dumper(\@answer);
```

Now it's the data structure you thought it should be:

```
Evaled =
$VAR1 = [
          'w',
          {
            'k2' => 5
          },
          'q',
          'duck'
        ];
```